# Do Devtas accept the offerings only by Brahmins?

Tags: brahmins

Traditionally only Brahmins are allowed to become priests . What is the reason behind this ? Do Devtas accept offerings only by Brahmins ?

Comment: depends how the offering made, if the offering is made through Agni i.e. Homa what we can purnaahuthi then require brahmin priest to officiate yagna.  if the offering is like dropping ones money in hundi of temple they can all do it themselves.. like doing dana.. out of all the methods of offerning doing through homa and purnaahuthi reaches God for sure other offerings one may not know directly.. like Agni, suppose you offer through temple hundi, but the temple is run secular govt, the money can go to govt and it may use it for non religious purpose, then the offering is not accepted by god

Comment: but one may not know, but in poornaahuti one can see that offering is burnt to ashes that mean Agni devatha had in indeed distubted to intending devathas.

Answer (score 4):

No .. Devas accept offering from not only the Brahmins. But when it comes to officiating for others, only Brahmins are allowed to do it. So while Kshatriyas etc. can worship for themselves they can not worship for others which only Brahmins are allowed to do.

See the following verses from Manu Smriti:

> 10.75. Teaching, studying, sacrificing for himself, **sacrificing for others,** making gifts and receiving them are the six acts
> (prescribed) for a Brahmana.
>
> 10.76. But among the six acts (ordained) for him three are his means of subsistence, (viz.) sacrificing for others, teaching, and accepting
> gifts from pure men.
>
> 10.77. (Passing) from the Brahmana to the Kshatriya, **three acts (incumbent on the former) are forbidden, (viz.) teaching, sacrificing
> for others,** and, thirdly, the acceptance of gifts.

So it is clear that Kshatriyas and others can worship for themselves but they can not officiate on behalf of others. It is forbidden for all others except Brahmins. That's why temple priests, who officiate for others, are only Brahmins.

Comment: IDK if I'm not able to understand it or not becoz I've a doubt. Will god not accept if a kshatriya or someone else apart from a Brahmana does it for others? Is god bounded by rules? Please clarify.

Comment: @LSSJBroly God is not bounded by rules, but rather we are bounded by rules that God has set on us.

Comment: Scriptures are regarded as orders of God settled by him. And as per scriptures a Ksatriya officiating for others is a forbidden task. So a law abiding Ksatriya would not do it in my view. Now how God will view such an act or whether God will accept the offering or not will depend on the merits of the situation I think @LSSJBroly

Comment: Thanks a lot rickross ji. Upvoted

Comment: Thanks ... @LSSJBroly